# How to extract JSON data as an object and change it to an array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have seen many other questions answering similar problems, however none of them seem to work for me or they use a library (I am in vanilla JS). Essentially, I have a .JSON file and I need to fetch the data from it and convert that data into an array so I can assign the data to different buttons in HTML. After the options are loaded, I need to repeat the process all over again. My original JSON fetching code is based off of [this article](https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/). Here is a basic JSON file I put together because my actual one is quite large:

```
{
"Mobile" : {
    "option 1" : {
        "optionA" : {
            "optionW" : {},
            "optionX" : {}
        },
        "optionB" : {
            "optionY" : {},
            "optionZ" : {}
        }
    },
    "option 2" : {}
},
"Desktop" : {}
}
```

Here is my Javascript:

```js
var dataToStartWith;

function cnt() {
  fetch('/web-app/data/help-tree.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      var selectedBtn = document.getElementById("optn-btn-ttl-" + optnchc).innerHTML;
      console.log(selectedBtn);
      if (dataToStartWith != undefined) {
        var dataToExtract = dataToStartWith += [selectedBtn];
      } else {
        var dataToExtract = data[0][selectedBtn];
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < dataToExtract.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("optn-btn-ttl")[i].innerHTML = dataToExtract[i];
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

}
```

The variable optn-chc returns what text is in the button that the user selected.
A theoretical example:
User selects the "mobile" option (Not part of the code I have included because the initial options are loaded with the page). Now, the user is presented with the options "option 1" and "option2". So on, and so forth.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: is the goal to transform the child nodes of the root nodes of the fetched object as array?  Do you need recursive depth?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPairs This can be used.  But you can also retain the shape of the Object and use `Object.keys(object)` to get the keys of an object and iterate over it like an array?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and see how it goes.